# What is the simplest way to get UTF-8 substring in Julia

Tags: utf-8, julia

UTF-8 string in Julia cannot use slice operator because it slice the byte index of string not character. For example

```
s = "ポケットモンスター"
s[1:4]
```

s[1:4] will be "ポケ" not "ポケット".

I would like to know the simplest and most readable for get UTF-8 sub-string in Julia.

Comment: A little awkward but `s[chr2ind(1):chr2ind(4)]` can get the first 4 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using `UTF32String` instead of `UTF8String`, if you are going to be doing this a lot, and only converting to `UTF8String` if necessary, when you are finished.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this question calls attention to some missing functions in the standard string library (which is supposed to undergo changes in the next version of Julia). In the meantime, if we define:

```
substr(s,i,j) = s[chr2ind(s,i):chr2ind(s,j)]
```

Then,

```
substr(s,1,4)
```

Would be `"ポケット"`